# How to select light as sun source

Tags: unity

I tried to add a sun in the lighting setting. I have a directional light in my scene, but i can't select it as sun source in lighting setting. The light does not appear in the list. Does anyone know what is wrong ?

Comment: When you open the tab, it defaults to "Assets" instead of "Scene", have you tried switching the tab ? or better, a classic drag & drop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your tab is set to "Scene" instead of "Assets" (shown in image), since it defaults to the latter.

[image: here]